# how to implement lazy loading of images in gridview

Tags: android

I want to load images in a grid view using lazy loading. I have tried to implement this by using AsyncTask bet it is throwing concurrent future task error.Am loading images from server by using URL so please help me.

Comment: Use Custom GridView for that.

Comment: thankyou for that bt I have already implemented that. i want to know how to use lazy loading?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this library `https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader` There is loading in every style... list, grid etc

Comment: thanks for this but i am loading images from server by using url,how to implement that?

Comment: its is there... just check it out

Comment: @AamirShah UniversalImageLoader is nice. But one issue what i got is. it is not storing images in catch. So everytime it is loading images from server. if it is storing images and display it from the catch then its great.

Answer (score 4):

Simple example showing lazy loading gridview for android.

https://github.com/desertjim/LazyLoadingGridView

Comment: I have also tried this but its not working for me, as I am loading images by using URL

Comment: give me some time . I will do that

Comment: Hey does it take care of memory usage??

Answer (score 0):

You can use [smart image view](http://loopj.com/android-smart-image-view/) that download the image form the HTTP url in the background. It is open source and its source code is available at [this link](https://github.com/loopj/android-smart-image-view)..

Comment: is this listview is lazy listview  ?

Comment: SmartImageView is a drop-in replacement for Android’s standard ImageView which additionally allows images to be loaded from URLs or the user’s contact address book. Images are cached to memory and to disk for super fast loading.

Comment: I think its is much difficult. Its good if you have demo . and you their link .

Comment: Their project page has sample code to integrate this view. following is the link to the project page: http://loopj.com/android-smart-image-view/

and it is easy since at can be used as the standard `ImageView`

Comment: ok. already this link is in ans. but I want demo . no problem . Thanks

Comment: Demo: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/the-missing-widget-in-the-android-sdk-smartimageview

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best link you can find around for working with images : http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html

The code is dedicated to ListViews but would work with GridView as well. It's quite complicated but performance is just stunning.