# fetch multiple images from url in android?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to implement lazy loading of images in gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626313/how-to-implement-lazy-loading-of-images-in-gridview)

How to fetch multiple images from url using Drawable in android?

```
private Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url) {
        try {
            InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "icon");
            return d;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exc=" + e);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I'm using this function to return drawable image but I'm not getting how to bind list of images to gridview..

Please help me.

Comment: Try looking into this [Link](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader). It does a lot of work out of the box for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply give url to "imgaeUrl" field

```
URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
HttpURLConnection connection  = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);  

imageView.setImageBitmap(img );
```

and set imageview

Comment: this code works fine for single image.. what to do for array of images?

Comment: @shivanipatel first yout all get into list  List<String> urls;  then and start for loop for(int i=0;i<url.length;i++) then yout call your method LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url) as you define first

Comment: for(int i=0; i<imageList.size(); i++){
      HashMap<String, String> hm = imageList.get(1);
      
      drawable.add(LoadImageFromWebOperations(hm.get(TAG_IMAGE)));
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), hm.get(TAG_IMAGE), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }

Comment: my list is returning hashmap so i have stored result in hash map bt it is giving me \null pointer execption.

Comment: show your logcat error or code @shivanipatel

Comment: it gives null pointer exception....

Comment: HashMap<String, String> hm=new HashMap<String, String> .. write before calling and use

Answer (score 0):

You can check this http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html.
 It can lead you