# Smoothly and infinity scrolling as inflikr Android app

Tags: android, scroll

I'm trying to build an photo gallery app, and then I have a look at the Inflikr app for Flickr on Google PLay Store.

What I really love from this App is that, even if you don't have the content, the gridview (in the top Activity) will scroll smoothly to the endless bottom (meaning no bottom at all). So my question is How could I adapt/create that kind of grid/list view?

What I have tried: I successfully created a paging gridview that will lazily load the content. But if I scroll the view to the bottom (then the gridview will load more content), it will stop there, wait for new content to be inserted by adapter, then user can continue scrolling. Now I want to be able to scroll endlessly event when new content hasn't been loaded.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see PagedCursor https://gist.github.com/pskink/b21c932f405740011144 and a testing provider https://gist.github.com/pskink/9ab862cdd0d6b0281ab4

Answer (score 2):

According to my understanding, you want to implement "Pagination with lazy loading". So I recommend you before directly start implementing it, you need to go to through below 2 things:

1. What is pagination?
2. What is lazy loading?

After googling & understanding above 2 things, you can refer these links so it'll be more helpful to you for faster implementation & understanding :

1. [Lazy download images into gridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13265457/lazy-download-images-into-gridview)
2. [how to implement lazy loading of images in gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626313/how-to-implement-lazy-loading-of-images-in-gridview)
3. [Android Using GridView with OnScrollListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12170466/android-using-gridview-with-onscrolllistener)

I'm quite sure these links will solve your problem.